# Calculating the probability of following event involving Brownian motion

Tags: probability, measure-theory, brownian-motion

I have a big time trouble in evaluating the following probability. It is related to brownian motion and measure, so I am asking experts from both fields for help!

Denote $B_t$, $t\in [0, T]$ be univariate Brownian motion on $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$ with filtration $\Sigma_t$ so that $\Sigma_T=\Sigma$. Now define a probability measure $M$ as follows. $$\forall K\in \Sigma:\;\; M(K)=\mathbb{E}[\exp(B_T-T/2)\mathbb{1}_K].$$
The question is to compute the probability 
$$M(\exp(B_T)-A\geq0)$$ where $A$ is a positive number.

This is what I did so far:

$$M(\exp(B_T)-A\geq0)=\mathbb{E}[\exp(B_T-T/2)\mathbb{1}_K] \geq\mathbb{E}[A\exp(-T/2)\mathbb{1}_K].$$
Then this implies 
$$M(\exp(B_T)-A\geq0) \geq A\exp(-T/2)\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_K]\geq A\exp(-T/2)P(\exp(B_T)-A\geq0)$$
Then I found that since $\exp(B_T)$ follows log normal then follows the CDF, we have $$P(\exp(B_T)-A\geq0)=1-\Phi(\ln A/ \sqrt{T})$$
Therefore, 
$$M(\exp(B_T)-A\geq0) \geq  A\exp(-T/2)[1-\Phi(\ln A/ \sqrt{T})]$$

Then I stop, since the question asks to find the exact answer, not the lower bound..but this is how I did and don't know how to proceed further..

Any help will be extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K=[\mathrm e^{B_T}\gt A]$, then $M(K)=E[\mathrm e^{B_T-T/2}\mathbf 1_K]=\mathrm e^{-T/2}\cdot E[\mathrm e^{B_T};B_T\gt\log A]$. For every $x$,
$$
E[\mathrm e^{B_T};B_T\gt x]=\int_x^{+\infty}\mathrm e^z\frac{\mathrm e^{-z^2/2T}}{\sqrt{2\pi T}}\mathrm dz.
$$
One completes the square as usual, that is, one uses the change of variable $z=T+\sqrt{T}u$, which yields
$$
E[\mathrm e^{B_T};B_T\gt x]=\mathrm e^{T/2}\int_{(x-T)/\sqrt{T}}^{+\infty}\frac{\mathrm e^{-u^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm du=\mathrm e^{T/2}\,\Phi(\sqrt{T}-x/\sqrt{T}).
$$
Finally,
$$
M[\mathrm e^{B_T}\gt A]=\Phi(\sqrt{T}-(\log A)/\sqrt{T}).
$$